# Searching Database with partial keyword

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-like, freetexttable

I'm trying to do a search of all the columns of a specific table and I want to return the result that contains certain characters. For example

`Entered Search Value: "Josh"`

`Output Values: Josh, Joshua, Joshie, Rich Joshua`

I want to return all values containing the characters `Josh`. I'm trying to use `FreeTextTable` however it only returns exact words like this

`Entered Search Value: "Josh"
Output Values: Josh`

I'm using the following code.

```
DECLARE @nameSearch NVARCHAR(100) = 'Josh';

SELECT MAX(KEY_TBL.RANK) as RANK, FT_TBL.ID
FROM Property FT_TBL 
INNER JOIN (SELECT Rank, [KEY]
            from FREETEXTTABLE(Property, *, @nameSearch)) AS KEY_TBL
ON FT_TBL.ID = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
GROUP BY FT_TBL.ID
```

I know this will be possible by using `LIKE` or `CONTAINS` but I have a lot of rows in that table and it would take time before it returns the result. So I need to use `FreeTextTable` to get the `Rank` and `Key`. However I can't achieve my goal here. I need help. Thanks!

Comment: Append " on both sides of @locationSearch and try to run the query               From this link: https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/9702.fts-freetext-freetexttable     -->  Note: If you wrap your FreeText or FreeTextTable search phrase in double quotes (ie â€œMy Searchâ€), the stemming and thesaurus features will be disabled and a Contains (or literal) search will be performed.

Comment: @Sujith nah, it doesn't work.